# How to override flutter apk manifest?

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I am working on updating Android Manifest configurations on my Flutter project. However, there is one recommended fix that I could not find in the libraries I have used in flutter. But upon analyzing the APK, I found it in the AndroidManifest.xml in the APK via APK Analyzer

[image]

Shown above is the config I have to update. A very simple update where I have to replace android:exported to false.

I need help in figuring out a way to actually update this manifest since I do not see any file even after looking through each manifest files of the packages I've included in my project that contains the code/config shown above.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the `exported` flag to false? FCM messaging won't work if you do that. It is permission protected so that only Google Play services can call it already.

Comment: I am only doing this as we were instructed by the client who hired some security analyst and one of the recommendation was to change the following https://imgur.com/lgida2J and change the exported value to false

Comment: Yeah, that'll break things quite completely. They are permission protected components, so they are already limited to only being called by the apps that hold those permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So I guess I couldn't find it because it shouldn't be updated in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in manifest

```
<application
tools:replace="android:label"
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
android:label="flutterwp" 
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? Because the manifest code shown above that I'm trying to update is not actually located in the main application's manifest, nor the packages/libraries manifest files

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit this AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: This is a merged manifest, the tag comes from a library. So editing is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tools:replace` attr.

Checkout following example from [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#attribute_markers):

- In library

```
<activity android:name="com.example.ActivityOne"
    android:theme="@oldtheme"
    android:exported="false"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" />
```

- Your own implementation

```
<activity android:name="com.example.ActivityOne"
    android:theme="@newtheme"
    android:exported="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:replace="android:theme,android:exported"
```

Comment: I cannot actually find the code shown in the picture (which I am trying to find) both in the applications manifest file, nor the libraries/packages manifest files

Comment: I didn't get the question then. Are you trying to update the manifest content when app is already built? In the code?

Comment: No, I am trying to find a way to update the receiver tags as shown in image above and add android:exported=false, so that when I build the APK, and analyze it, it would show the android:exported=false in the AndroidManifest file within the APK

Comment: So you want to change all receiver tags (even the ones you don't even know). Are trying to do this using code? Or SOmething like APKtool is valid?

Comment: I would ideally want to do this via code since I'm not the one building the APK on production. However, ianhanniballake has pointed that this would actually break things. So I decided not to proceed with this, and move on to other problems.